# How to check ALL elements of a boolean array are true

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I have a boolean array whose size depends on the size of a randomly selected string.

So I have something like this:

```
boolean[] foundLetterArray = new boolean[selectedWord.length()];
```

As the program progresses, this particular boolean array gets filled with true values for each element in the array. I just want to print a statement as soon as all the elements of the array are true. So I have tried:

```
if(foundLetterArray[selectedWord.length()]==true){
    System.out.println("You have reached the end");
}
```

This gives me an out of bounds exception error. I have also tried `contains()` method but that ends the loop even if 1 element in the array is true. Do I need a for loop that iterates through all the elements of the array? How can I set a test condition in that?

Comment: Array indices start at 0, so the last element is `foundLetterArray[selectedWord.length() - 1]`. Also `== true`  is a bit redundant; you don't need to compare a truth value to another, but can use it directly as the condition.

Comment: You need a loop to check whether all the elements are `true`. In the loop you can stop when you encounter the first `false` element.

Comment: Cheers guys. This solves the out of bound problem, but this if statement assumes the whole array is true if only the last element is true. Any ideas on how to get around that? For example if all elements are false and the last element is true, it says "You have reached the end". Is that true? or have I done something wrong again?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the **enhanced for loop**, you can easily iterate over an array, no need for indexes and size calculations:

```
private static boolean allTrue (boolean[] values) {
    for (boolean value : values) {
        if (!value)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: How can I use this method to print a "You have reached the end" statement once the whole array is checked? I dont understand this loop.

Comment: You can use this method to check your array: System.out.println ("Reached the end, all true: "+allTrue(foundLetterArray));

Comment: Can I use an if statement with this? Something like if(allTrue(foundLetterArray)==true){System.out.print("End reahed");

Comment: yes, and even shorter:  if(allTrue(foundLetterArray)){System.out.print("End reahed");

Comment: I didnt know about an enhanced for loop, I dont understand it, but I have made it work through trial and error! Thanks Peter! My program is now complete.

Comment: What about return !Arrays.toString(booleanArray).contains("false");

Answer (score 4):

There is a Java 8 one-liner for this:

```
boolean allTrue(boolean[] arr) {
    return IntStream.range(0, arr.length).allMatch(i -> arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

boolean[] foundLetterArray = new boolean[5];
The memory allocation for the abow array is like

```
      foundLetterArray[0],foundLetterArray[1],foundLetterArray[2],foundLetterArray[3],foundLetterArray[4]
```

Array index starts with 0 and the total memory count is 5 and the last array index is 4.

You are trying to get index 5 that is foundLetterArray[5] which does not exist. That's why you are getting the `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException`

```
   if(foundLetterArray[selectedWord.length()-1]==true){
      System.out.println("You have reached the end");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Java starts from `index 0` and last index is always `[array.length()-1]`

As you are checking for `foundLetterArray[selectedWord.length()]` ,its giving you a array out of Bound Exception try `foundLetterArray[selectedWord.length()-1]`

Like:

```
if(foundLetterArray[selectedWord.length()-1]){
System.out.println("You have reached the end");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indices in java, as well as most programming languages, are 0-based, meaning that individual elements in an array with n elements have indices 0, 1, 2, ..., n-1. The last element in an array is always at index array.length - 1.

Answer (score 0):

Array index start from 0 so last index is always 1 less then array length so here you are trying to access last index + 1 by doing foundLetterArray[selectedWord.length()] this so it is throuing ArrayIndexBoundEception use array.lastIndex() method or subtract 1 form length.

Implementing this `foundLetterArray[selectedWord.length()-1]` You must take care about one thing if your array does not contains any elements then selectedWord.length() return 0 and again you will get same exception so Its good to check lengh before doing this `foundLetterArray[selectedWord.length()-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
public boolean allTrue(boolean[] array) {
    for (boolean b : array) {
        if (!b) {
           return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

There is no 'one line' way of knowing whether all of the elements of an array meet a certain condition (there are libraries that take care of the looping for you, but you still need to write the condition). Querying array[x] will only tell you about the xth item in that array, so for your question you need to check every item.

Also, as other people have pointed out, array indices are 0-based, so the first element is at array[0] and the last at array[array.length() - 1].

My example uses an alternate looping construct known as for-each. This is appropriate when you don't need to modify the array contents, you only need to read from them. It avoids any messing around with indices.

Answer (score 0):

You do the check only for last element in the array ( and do it wrong, above is described why ).

In order to get if arrays contains only true values you should check all of them.

```
boolean allAreTrue = true;
for (boolean val : foundLetterArray) {
  allAreTrue = allAreTrue && val;
}
```

// at this line allAreTrue will contain true if all values are true and false if you have at least one "false"

Comment: This is inefficient since it won't stop if a false value is encountered.

Comment: No it's not, that's not readable at all for a beginner. And teaching poor code is not beneficial for anyone.